# Block or redirect requests to specific path or domain in Selenium

Tags: ruby, testing, selenium, proxy, capybara

I'm using Selenium through Capybara to automate tests run with Cucumber. I'm loading some pages that reference content on a CDN. I have no interest in creating more requests than necessary and hitting the CDN without reason. I'd like to configure Selenium to ignore requests to that domain somehow.

Celerity has a method like this:

```
Browser.ignore_pattern("regex pattern")
```

That will ignore any requests created that match. I'd like to replicate this feature in some manner. Is there a way to override DNS to go to 0.0.0.0 or some other way to configure the internal Selenium proxy?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the browsermob-proxy-rb gem found at https://github.com/jarib/browsermob-proxy-rb to blacklist your CDN.

The following was largely stolen from the github listing's README:

```rb
require 'selenium/webdriver'
require 'browsermob/proxy'

server = BrowserMob::Proxy::Server.new("/path/to/download/browsermob-proxy") #=> #<BrowserMob::Proxy::Server:0x000001022c6ea8 ...>
server.start

proxy = server.create_proxy #=> #<BrowserMob::Proxy::Client:0x0000010224bdc0 ...>

profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new #=> #<Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile:0x000001022bf748 ...>

# This is the line I added
proxy.blacklist(/path.to.CDN.com/)

profile.proxy = proxy.selenium_proxy

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => profile

driver.get "http://www.yoursite.com"
```